# How can I exclude a particular genre of music from playlists on Pandora?

Tags: pandora, pandora-playlist

I would like to know how can I take Gospel music out of my stations.  I use Pandora a lot while I workout and although I like Gospel, I don't want to hear it during my workout. I play Pandora at home sometimes when i have small gatherings and on one station it will go from "My Goodies" to "We Fall Down", almost inappropriately.

I know it can be done I'm just not sure how to do it. Can someone help me out?